# GitHub Action: How to get value from expression evaluation and assign it to the environment variable

Tags: github-actions

An environment expression is often assigned directly like the example below

```
  - name: set up env var
    env:
      TAG: v1.2.3
    run: echo $TAG
```

But how can I get the value from shell script evaluation? For example in my terminal I can get the current Tag by `git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')`

but when I try to put this script into the env as follow

```
  - name: set up env var
    env:
      TAG: $(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))
    run: echo $TAG
```

the echo printed out `$(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))` which means it is not evaluated but treated as a string.

How can I get the value of `git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')` and assign it to the environment variable `TAG` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add variables to the `GITHUB_ENV` by using: `echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

*This allows to create or update an environment variable for any actions running next in a job. The action that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent actions in a job will have access. Environment variables are case-sensitive and you can include punctuation.*

[Source](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

So your workflow could for example look like this:

```yaml
 - name: set up env var
    run: echo "TAG=$(echo git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
 - name: use env var
    run: echo ${{ env.TAG }}
```

Comment: Got an error: Unable to interpolate string 'echo "TAG=$(echo git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))"

Comment: I tried it [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5141173597?check_suite_focus=true) and didn't get this error (I just don't have tag set). The workflow implementation is [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow_tester23.yml), I just divided the commands to check step by step.

Comment: I know why it was not run for me. I put echo command together with the environmental set up in the same step. You can't use it right way in the same step

Comment: I guess I have to remove one of the echo in my answer then, right?

Comment: It solves my issue and runs perfectly.

Comment: How about an `env` that is set at the top level of a workflow file ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve exactly @challet?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I would have liked to define envs at the top level to be shared among jobs (like [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow) for instance). I think I found since then that there cannot be any expression there.

Comment: You can use some expressions at the workflow level for env variables, but not everything works. I've got some examples: [1](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/58-env-expressions.yml), [2](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/53-concatenation.yml), [3](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/10-environment-workflow.yml)