# Dynamic naming for build artifacts zip file

Tags: github, github-actions, git-workflow

in my repo, I have yml file with the code below /.github/workflows/filename.yml

```
 -  name: Create Artifact
     uses: actions/upload-artifiact@v2
     with:
       name: Report.22.9.zip
       path: |
         project
         !project/Reports/*
         !project/Logs/*
         !project/Snapshots/*
```

Now, I'm trying to make "name: Report.22.9.zip" more dynamic. Something like this

```
<repo_name>.<branch_name>.<git_build_id>.zip
```

Comment: You can add those variables as environment variable and then use `${{ env.REPO_NAME }}.${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}.${{ env.GIT_BUILD_ID }}>.zip`.

Comment: [Here is a reference to add a new ENV variable to the workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041571/github-action-how-to-get-value-from-expression-evaluation-and-assign-it-to-the/71042503#71042503)

Comment: You cannot use env variables in paths as far as I know

Comment: You can use env variables as action inputs. If it's a path, just be careful with spaces or special characters. As here it would be for a name, there shouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can create artifact name in previous step and provide it as output to be used by artifact upload step.

```
name: Dynamic artifact name

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Generate artifact name
        id: generate-name
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=artifact::${{ github.event.repository.name }}.${{ github.ref_name }}.${{ github.run_id }}.zip"

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ steps.generate-name.outputs.artifact }}
          path: ./README.md
```

Comment: set-output is deprecated though.. scheduled to be remove.. sigh https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/